# Deserializing protobuf from C++ and reserializing in C# gives different output

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a file with a protobuf message in it in byte format, when I read the file and deserialize the protobuf it works fine (I can read the objects fields and they are correct), however, when I reserialize it and save it back to a file, some bytes are different from the original (causing compatibility issues).

More specifically, after a string and before a bool theres the bytes '18 00' added.

I tried playing around with the DataFormat options from protobuf-net to get the exact same result as the original, but to no avail.

Does anyone know of any options in protobuf-net in regards to saving a string or a bool which could explain the extra 2 bytes?

Also, a ulong is being saved differently in bytes aswell.

I don't have control over the original file, I only know it's compiled/serialized with c++

My goal is to recreate the exact same file (bytewise) by serializing in c#, so it is identical to the file serialized by c++.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact bytes you are trying to reproduce and the data involved? `18 00` (assuming that is hex, not decimal) is "field 3, wire-type varint, value 0". Feel free to ping me on email if the data is not suitable for public forum, etc

Comment: Please show a short but complete example - at least in terms of the message description and the message data. Could it be a field with a default value which is omitted in C++ and included in C#?

Comment: @MarcGravell sent you an e-mail with 2 binary files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to how properties are handled. By default,

```
protogen -i:my.proto -o:my.cs
```

generates simple properties, of the form:

```
private bool _some_value = default(bool);
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name=@"some_value",
    DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(default(bool))]
public bool some_value
{
  get { return _some_value; }
  set { _some_value = value; }
}
```

This is fine for most scenarios, but doesn't *quite* support every "was a value actually specified?" scenario.

However, you can do instead:

```
protogen -i:my.proto -o:my.cs -p:detectMissing
```

which generates the much more thorough:

```
private bool? _some_value;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name=@"some_value",
    DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
public bool some_value
{
  get { return _some_value?? default(bool); }
  set { _some_value = value; }
}
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
[global::System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
public bool some_valueSpecified
{
  get { return this._some_value != null; }
  set { if (value == (this._some_value== null))
      this._some_value = value ? this.some_value : (bool?)null; }
}
private bool ShouldSerializesome_value() { return some_valueSpecified; }
private void Resetsome_value() { some_valueSpecified = false; }
```

This has full support for tracking explicit assignment, including support for most UI-binding and serialization frameworks (not just protobuf-net).

The 2-byte difference is simply the difference between "false, not serialized due to implicit default value" and "false, known to be explicitly specified as false, and thus serialized".

So the fix is: include the `-p:detectMissing` when using protogen.